# How to show menu list at hover on icon using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have dynamic icons on page. I want to show drop down menu list at hover on icon.
Actually i tried with div but this div showing at fix location but i want that list beside to respective icon.
is this possible??
Please Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some code here.. or provide us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with only CSS like this: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

or with JS (jQuery) like so: http://www.queness.com/post/1047/easy-to-style-jquery-drop-down-menu-tutorial